# XUL JS printing error to console

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

I am really a XUL starter, i am desperately trying to write an application that will print "Hello world" to console when a button presses, i need to display debugging information also. Although i didn't find impressive documentation and tutorial for XUL dummies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out if this helps:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_a_XULRunner_Application